# How to set Global Environment Variables from a file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkin pardon me for any wrong statements. 
I have to set Global Environment Variables from a File(say config or txt) and I want to place that file either in my local or somewhere on the server.

I have gone through some documentations but it all says to use EnvInject Plugin which is basically helps for a specific job when we are building it.

But I want a solution where Global env variables can fetch from the file so that Configure System page can load quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are looking  to read properties from a specific file and inject them as environment variables to your jenkins job.

You can follow below approach:
Create property file like env.properties with below content:
testvalue='mytest'

Sample code to read the file and inject read variables as environment variables

node`{load "${WORKSPACE}\env.properties" 
     echo "test value: ${testvalue}"
 }

Comment: Does this work for Global Variables as well, I don't think so, this above solution may work for Individual Jobs but not for reading Global Env Variables.
And my question has nothing to do with a Job. 
I have 10-15 Global Variables placed under Configure System, coz of which page takes some time to load, so I dont want all the global variables on GUI instead place them in a file on a server or local.